# Calculate the average grade Leslie must make in order to receive a B for the math class?

Tags: average

Leslie is taking a math class. This is how the class is graded.
Test 1  13%
Test 2  13%
Test 3  13%
Lab 1   10%
Lab 2   10%
Lab 3   10%
Lab 4   10%
Final Exam   21%

She received a 93% on Lab 1, 70% on Test 1, 29% on Lab 2, and 50% on Test 2
What must she receive on Lab 3,4,Test #3 and the Final exam in order to have an 80% for the class.

Comment: While I don't think the question is very useful, nor does it show a whole lot of effort, I will say that [a simple calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=93*.1%2B70*.13%2B29*.1%2B50*.13%2Bx*%28.13%2B.1%2B.1%2B.21%29%3E%3D80) show that a 96.67% average is needed on the remaining activities, so it might be useful to start working (or to demand extra credit).

Answer (score 1):

$$(13\%*70\%)
+(13\%*50\%)
+(13\%*x)
+(10\%*93\%)
+(10\%*29\%)
+(10\%*x)
+(10\%*x)
+(21\%*x) = 80\%$$

$$27.8\% + 54\%*x = 80\%$$
$$54\%*x = 52.2\% $$
$$x = 96.67\% $$

Comment: 80% - 27.8% = 52.2% (and not 61.3%)

Comment: I knew something was wrong with that picture. Thanks.